# What languages should I learn to develop a social network like Facebook?

Tags: facebook, twitter, programming-languages, client-side, server-side

I'm talking about both server-side and client-side. I know a little bit about Go, JavaScript, Node.js, PHP, Ruby and Java.
I'm not trying to hit the goal in a few days, which I know is senseless. I plan to start by developing small apps for platforms like Twitter, Google+, especially Facebook, and in the end develop a whole platform like Facebook.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to learn languages, you need to learn Algorithms & Data Structures. You also need to know something about Distributed Computing, Scalabilty, Performance, Information Retrieval, Machine Learning, Collective Intelligence, Wisdom Of Crowd, Natural Language Processing, Kevin Bacon 6 degrees of separation, Graph Theory and few more topics.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into these topics.

Answer (score 0):

Read all the volumes written by Donald Knuth.  You are ready.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks for pointing him out. I'll find his books.